# How can I delete a Tkinter StringVar character by character in Python?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am new to Python and learning Tkinter now. I am working on a simple calculator and need to define a function for the `Erase` button in my project to delete the entered number character by character (not just cleaning the entry at once).

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can overwrite your existing string with a string containing all characters except the last one:

Example with a Tkinter StringVar:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
text = tk.StringVar()
text.set('Hello world')
text.set(text.get()[0:-1]) # Hello worl (the "d" was removed)
tk.Label(root, textvariable=text).grid()
root.mainloop()
```

Example with a simple Python string:

```
text = "Hello world"
text = text[0:len(text)-1]
print(text) # Hello worl (the "d" was removed)
```

The method `len(text)` returns the length of the string, then we read from the first character (`0`) up to the penultimate one (`len(text)-1]`) and overwrite the existing string.

As [@jasonharper](http://jasonharper) has pointed out, you can replace `text[0:len(text)-1]` with `text[0:-1]`, which looks cleaner and has the same practical effect.

Comment: You don't actually need `len()` here, `text = text[0:-1]` does the same thing (negative numbers in slices are interpreted relative to the length of the string).

Comment: That's true, I'll add that to the answer. Thank you!

Comment: thanks for your help,I do appreciate it but I have another question regarding this solution,does it work for Stringvar() too?cause I am using Stringvar to get numbers in my Entry

Comment: @kimia I updated the answer with the same logic being applied to a Tkinter StringVar.

Comment: @TelmoTrooper thanks a million.you solved my problem.thanks again for your help